# Should Elasticsearch 6 be deployed in the same server or virtual server as Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 6 is the new default and recommended catalog search for Magento 2 and I learned that it should not be deployed in the same server (vm) as Magento 2. Is it acceptable to have elasticsearch in the same server as a Magento 2 store? and If it is acceptable what would be an acceptable memory allowance in a cloud instance with 8gb ram available for everything?

Answer (score 1):

Possible yes. Recommend no. Although in today's world of instances and cloud computing they could technically be on same server but within different VMs and cause no impact.

As for memory depends how busy your store is and how many automated processes are running. 8gb is a little low. I'd say between 10 and 12 gb.

Comment: Ok. My cloud instance has 8 gb total. My store has only 100 visitors a day. Do you think is ok to configure elasticsearch like this
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms512m
-Xmx512m

Comment: So concurrent users would be 1 - 6? Still a little low. Magento is a bit of a memory hog.

Comment: About 6 concurrent users. I'm getting about 350 visitors a day.

Comment: Yes I would say min 1 GB per concurrent user with additional 2 GB for search. That's assuming php memory_limit is around 512mb. You need a buffer for mysql memory requirements. As soon as memory is low your install will slow down as you will start to use the hard disk if swap space is configured. Things like mysqltuner help. One environment differs greatly to another so this is just a guide.

Answer (score 0):

it can be anywhere, but if you have lots of products and traffic and big data storage, it is better to run it from separate server.

in your case you can limit its memory and control storage space, and run it on the same server.